# Looking for an After Effects feature in Blender (Expressions)?

Tags: animation, scripting, timeline

In after effects there is a feature where you can write a quick code to automatically animate something. i.e. say you want something to slightly "wiggle" you can type wiggle (2,30) and it will automatically wiggle when moving the timeline.

Or say I want something to scale in and out automatically, In AE I can just type time*10 and it will automatically scale in and out with the timeline.

Is there anything like this for Blender?

Comment: The closest thing to use is probably drivers. Not as easy and quick but is very powerful, especially if you don't mind some coding.

Comment: Yeah drivers are what you want and are pretty easy to do once you understand how to get them working. Although I often just use an animated empty to influence other objects.

Answer (score 1):

Not that extensive. In the grapheditor you can use modifiers for your animations, like noise, which makes it the selected line(s) of keyframes wiggle. It's very limited.

It would make a good addon tho....

Comment: What bothers me is how many addons there are that could add amazing functionality to Blender. I really wish Blender would consider actually implementing the code of some addons (e.g. the VSE Transform Tools) so that they can work seamlessly and are more widely acknowledged.